# Why this code is not updating the database & giving exception?

Tags: java, date, database-connection

I am trying to update the database with a date received from a textfield in date format. But its not working and giving me a java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string "". Please help.

```
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String date = i5t1.getText();
    try
    {
    i5Date=(Date) formatter.parse(date);
    }
    catch(ParseException p)
    {
    p.printStackTrace();
    }

    PreparedStatement i5ps = i5conn.prepareStatement("Select * from DailyAnalysis");
    i5ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(i5Date.getTime()));
    ResultSet i5rs = i5ps.executeQuery();
```

**EDITS :**

I am adding a small program, but this one doesnt compile due to some error, ***reference to Date is ambiguous, both class java.util.Date in java.util and class java.sql.Date match
Date i5Date1=formatter.parse(date1);***

This sql date and util date are very much confusing.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.event.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;

public class Problem {

JFrame frame;
JPanel panel;
JButton saveButton;
JTextField dateField;
JLabel dateLabel;



public Problem() {
    frame = new JFrame();
    panel = new JPanel();
    frame.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    dateLabel = new JLabel("Date");
    dateField = new JTextField(20);
    saveButton = new JButton("Save");
    saveButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener()
   {@Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
         {
try
{
    Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
    Connection i5conn = DriverManager.getConnection("Jdbc:Odbc:TomsJava");
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    String date1 = dateField.getText();
    try
    {
    Date i5Date1=formatter.parse(date1);
    }
    catch(ParseException p)
    {
    p.printStackTrace();
    }
    String query= "Select * from DailyAnalysis where Date1=?";
    PreparedStatement i5ps = i5conn.prepareStatement(query);

    i5ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(i5Date1.getTime()));

    ResultSet i5rs = i5ps.executeQuery();

                }

catch(SQLException e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
catch(ClassNotFoundException z)
{
    System.out.println(z);
}
catch(NumberFormatException n)
{
    System.out.println(n);
}
  }
});

    panel.add(dateLabel);
    panel.add(dateField);
    panel.add(saveButton);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new Problem();
        }
     });
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you think it happens  given `NumberFormatException: For input string ""`? There's only one reason..

Comment: what is the value of String date ??

Comment: i inputted 10-02-2013 in the textbox.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis - i am not understanding wheres the null string?

Comment: The `String` isn't null. It's the empty `String`.

Comment: I am a beginner, the code is inside a saveButton, so can u please tell me why date is an empty String? how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with your prepared statement,

```
PreparedStatement i5ps = i5conn.prepareStatement("Select * from DailyAnalysis");
```

There is no parameter in your above statement even though you are trying to set some data in your statement as follows:

```
i5ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(i5Date.getTime()));
```

It seems you want to get `DailyAnalysis` based on date value so your PreparedStatement should be as follows (I am assuming your `DailyAnalysis` table relevant column name is `date`, change it as per your table column name) :

```
PreparedStatement i5ps = i5conn.prepareStatement("Select * from DailyAnalysis where date=?");
i5ps.setDate(1, new java.sql.Date(i5Date.getTime()));
```

Try with above. Hopefully it should work.

**Just an advice:** Try to learn how to debug your code and how to analyse the exception to find the root cause. It would really help you in long run.

Comment: @Toms What is the issue now you are getting? have you changed the date column name? Modify your question and add more details like relevant lines of code, error trace details etc as it has been put on hold.

Comment: the error is same in my main program . But i have tried to make a mini program, this doesnt compile, ill post with the error.